# Aggregate before and after a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, postgresql

I have two tables: db.transactions and db.salesman, which I would like to combine in order to create an output that has aggregated sales before each salesman's hire date and after each salesman's hire date.

```
select * from db.transactions

index  sales_rep   sales  trx_date
1         Tom        200   9/18/2020
2         Jerry      435   6/21/2020
3         Patrick   1400   4/30/2020
4         Tom        560   5/24/2020
5         Francis    240    1/2/2021
```

```
select * from db.salesman 
index   sales_rep     hire_date    
1        Tom            8/19/2020  
2        Jerry          1/28/2020  
3        Patrick         4/6/2020  
4        Francis         9/4/2020
```

I would like to aggregate sales from db.transactions before and after each sales rep's hire date.

Expected output:

```
index   sales_rep     hire_date    agg_sales_before_hire_date    agg_sales_after_hire_date  
1        Tom            8/19/2020         1200                           5000
2        Jerry          1/28/2020          500                            900
3        Patrick         4/6/2020         5000                            300
4        Francis         9/4/2020         2900                           1500
```

For a single sales rep, to calculate the agg_sales_before_hire_date is likely:

```
select tx.sales_rep, tx.sum(sales)
from db.transactions tx
inner join db.salesman sm on sm.sales_rep = tx.sales_rep
where hire_date < '8/19/2020' and sales_rep = 'Tom'
group by tx.sales_rep
```

PostGRESQL. I am also open to the idea of doing it into Tableau or Python.

Comment: How do you have transaction before the hire date?

Comment: sales rep goes to a trial period before the hire date. the information should be in db.transactions

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CROSS JOIN LATERAL

```sql
select 
    sa.sales_rep, sa.hire_date,
    l.agg_sales_before_hire_date, 
    l.agg_sales_after_hire_date
from salesman sa
cross join lateral
(
 select 
   sum(tx.sales) filter (where tx.trx_date < sa.hire_date) agg_sales_before_hire_date,
   sum(tx.sales) filter (where tx.trx_date >= sa.hire_date) agg_sales_after_hire_date
 from transactions tx
 where tx.sales_rep = sa.sales_rep     
) l;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select tx.sales_rep, 
       sum(case when tx.txn_date < sm.hire_date then sales else 0 end) as before_sales,
       sum(case when tx.txn_date >= sm.hire_date then sales else 0 end) as after_sales
from db.transactions tx inner join
     db.salesman sm
     on sm.sales_rep = tx.sales_rep
group by tx.sales_rep;
```

EDIT:

In Postgres, you would use `filter` for the logic:

```
select tx.sales_rep, 
       sum(sales) filter (where tx.txn_date < sm.hire_date) as before_sales,
       sum(sales) filter (where tx.txn_date >= sm.hire_date then sales) as after_sales
```